# Displaying a form for filtering in custom post type listing

Tags: custom-post-types

In the UNU website under the Experts section (http://unu.edu/experts) there's a form where you can filter the experts by their institute and expertise area.

This is what it looks like:
[image]

I understand that the experts are stored in custom post types "expert". But I don't understand how the search form is built so that users can filter experts by selecting their institution and research topics?

Specifically:

- How to build data structure into the `Expert` type, i.e. how to link
  an expert with attributes like "institution" and "research area"?
- With the above data structure built, how to include a filter for `Expert` listing as shown in the screenshot above?

I would appreciate if you could explain the general idea how it's implemented; or is there a plugin so I don't have to reinvent?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Trix for your comment. I revised the question a bit and I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to build data structure into the Expert type, i.e. how to link an expert with attributes like "institution" and "research area"?

**Answer**
You may use [Taxomonies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) in wordpress, to add extra level od categorization of your posts. In your example, [you may register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) `Institution` and `Research area` taxonomies for your `Experts` custom post type.

> With the above data structure built, how to include a filter for Expert listing as shown in the screenshot above?

**Answer**
You may [use an ajax call](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) to pass the filter criteria and receive related experts from the server.